# Validate address info during customer registration using Azure AD B2C SignUp page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a specific scenario to validate an “Address” entered by the user in the b2c SignUp page. I’m thinking of using a google API to validate the customer address during the registration process. Is there any better approach to handle this validation using b2c custom policies on the Signup page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, validating external information via an API is the standard way of doing this.

Comment: Okay. Is there any references on this approach?

Comment: Lots of API examples - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples

Comment: Thanks. I’m able to verify the address info during registration now.